# 3d objects not present in Blend for Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: xaml, 3d, visual-studio-2017, expression-blend, blend

Tutorials and documentation about previous versions of Expression Blend talk about importing 3d objects, or creating 3d objects from images, and using cameras and lights. When trying to create a Windows Universal application (C++) I cannot see any of the elements concerned with 3d objects manipulation, and I can't find any explanation for this on the Internet. Have they removed these feature? Is there somewhere an older version of Blend that I can download to use 3d objects?

Answer (score 0):

This is so disappointing. I upgraded from VS 2013 to VS 2017 and found out that the "Make Image 3D" menu option was removed in Blend 2017.

Since I was using this feature a lot I think I will have to install both versions and just copy and paste the XAML code from Blend 2013 to Blend 2017.

Comment: What is your solution you are using know?